# override SaveChangesAsync

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller

I am trying to implement an audit trail on MVC project , by overriding the context by adding another peice of functionality (to so the audit).
The overriding of SaveChanges works fine, however the problem I have is with SaveChangesAsync.
Here is part the code from the context

```
    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("User ID must be provided");
    }


    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("User ID must be provided");
    }


    public async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(int userId)
    {
        DecidSaveChanges(userId);
        return await this.SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken.None);
    }


    public  int SaveChanges(int userId)
    {
        DecidSaveChanges(userId);
       return base.SaveChanges();
    }
```

The problem I have is with my controller

```
    await db.SaveChangesAsync(1);
```

1 being a dummy user. I get the following error.

```
 Error  1   The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult>'.
```

do you know what I am doing wrong here? and how to fix it?. I am using EF6 and MVC5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> do you know what I am doing wrong here?

Yes, just look at your compiler error message:

```
The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method.
```

So, the controller action (that contains the call to `SaveChangesAsync(1)`) needs to be `async`.

> and how to fix it?

Yes, just look at your compiler error message:

```
Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task<System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult>'.
```

So, you fix it by making the controller action `async` and changing its return type from `ActionResult` to `Task<ActionResult>`.